# Solve limit with Riemann sum.

Tags: calculus, limits

Hello I'm currently studying for my Calculus 2 exam and i have a pretty good grasp up until now. I'm having problems finding a good explanation on how to solve limits with Riemann sums. Can someone please explain for this particular problem. All other problems are similar to this one so if i know how to solve it i can solve all of them.

The problem in question is ,

$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2+n^2}{n^3+1} $

Comment: Can you show us what you know and what you've tried?

Comment: @AndrewLi i know how to solve these when i have a given interval let's say [1,4]. As for this type i don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{k^2+n^2}{n^3+1}}$$ by the method of Riemann sums, note that we need to express the sum as an average, so we will divide by $n$, which means we will want $\Delta x$ to equal $1/n$.  Unfortunately, we have $n^3+1$ in the denominator, but we can replace it by $n^3,$ since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3}{n^3+1}=1$$

So now, we can write $$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{k^2+n^2}{n^3+1}}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{k^2+n^2}{n^3}}=
\lim_{\Delta x\to 0+}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\Delta x}(1+(k \Delta x)^2)=\int_0^1{(1+x^2)dx} 
$$

**EDIT** Following up on the OP's comment, sometimes you have to be flexible.  Suppose that we had  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{k^2+n^2}{n^2+1}}$$

Now we have the divisor given to us, but we're dividing by $n$ and there are $n+1$ terms.  We can pull out the $k=0$ term however, to get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+1}+
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{k^2+n^2}{n^2+1}}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{k^2+n^2}{n^2}}=
\int_0^1{(1+x^2)dx} 
$$

Comment: Thank you very much @saulspatz. May i ask is every problem like this on the interval [0,1]? I'm really curious how you found that out.

Comment: I don't want to commit myself top saying *every* such problem turns into an integral on $[0,1]$ but I think most of them do.  As I said at the beginning of my answer, the key is usually look at the limit as the limit of an arithmetic average, and since there are $n$ terms in the sum, we want to divide by $n$.  I'm going to add a bit more to my answer, because I can't fit it in the comment.